# precompiled header clang redefinition of error

Tags: c++, clang

Trying to create a minimally reporducible example here:

```
#include "test.hpp"

int main() {
    printMe();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose test.hpp is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

void printMe(){
    std::cout<<"hey me you"<<std::endl;
}
```

Now in the terminal I run

`clang++ -std=c++2a test.hpp`

Which is successful and creates test.hpp.gch, but when I run:

`clang++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ -include-pch test.hpp.gch`

I get:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./test.hpp:7:6: error: redefinition of 'printMe'
void printMe(){
     ^
./test.hpp:7:6: note: previous definition is here
void printMe(){
     ^
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce that with your example (bogus) code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f84ce30fc6ea5ded Maybe, try `inline` with your real code.

Comment: That's a lousy dupe (or, rather, the dupe has lousy answers).  The correct solution is to declare the function(s) `inline`.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, as is the question :-P